# Avoiding lambda and stream usage for a class used at VM Startup

Tags: java, lambda, jvm, startup, java-9

Going through the `java.lang.module` I read amongst a class documentation the following:

> ```
> @implNote ... is used at VM startup and so deliberately
> avoids using lambda and stream usages in code paths used during
> startup.
> ```

**What are the causes from using lambda and streams that are avoided here and what are their possible impacts?**

Illustrations would help understand better, not looking for opinions here though.

Comment: @Ravi Yes I am ([early access build](http://jdk.java.net/9/)). The question is not related to its release but an implementation.

Comment: you need to tag correctly. If you are using it jdk8.

Comment: @Ravi There are plenty of questions tagged with java-9, to answer *if something is not released then, how can someone tell you about their usage*. And I am sure, I am using jdk-9+181. Hence the tag. I hope am able to explain that I understand what tags I 've placed.

Comment: Ohh.. hoping you get the answer then.

Comment: Why do you care about an internal Java VM startup sequence issue, where using lambda and/or stream before they are fully initialized can be problematic? It's not like it's ever going to affect *you*, since code you write as a regular programmer will run after initialization of the Java Runtime has completed.

Comment: Assume it is from here https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blame/master/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/module/Resolver.java

Strange since the java.util.stream and java.util.function API as well as java.lang.module are all part of the java.base.  Maybe just to avoid loading a lot of classes early at startup?

Comment: @Andreas *since code you write as a regular programmer will run after initialization of the Java Runtime has completed* is understood. But the question is somewhat on the lines, Java introduced something in their release jdk8 but then refrained from using the same in their own next version. There must be some reason/con pertaining to that. And *It's not like it's ever going to affect you*, I would like to know what is **its** here and then decide if it would affect me or not.

Comment: @YuriSchimke Not precisely the link, but seems like someone cloned the similar file there. Also, wouldn't the `java.base` be loaded anyway during startup?

Comment: Can't say for sure, but this is very likely to avoid start up performance regressions (e.g. due to class loading). Start up time is an important performance metric, so a few milliseconds can matter. The idea would be that if you don't absolutely need it (and there _does_ exist alternatives to streams), don't use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not relying on lambdas and streams (that extensively use lambdas) helps to avoid doing redundant work at VM bootstrap. That in turn reduces startup time and memory footprint.

`invokedynamic` machinery in JDK is rather complex. It involves many `java.lang.invoke.*` classes related to Method Handles, Lambda Metafactories etc. that need to be loaded and initialized. Furthermore, to link `invokedynamic` bytecode JVM dynamically creates an adapter using ObjectWeb ASM framework. Generating such classes in runtime also takes time and space.

Let's measure an overhead of using lambda instead of inner class in a very basic scenario. I create two similar classes that do nothing but instantiating either an inner class or a lambda:

```
class Inner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() { public void run() {} };
        r.run();
    }
}

class Lambda {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {};
        r.run();
    }
}
```

Then I run both with class loading log turned on:

```
java -Xlog:class+load:file=inner.log Inner
java -Xlog:class+load:file=lambda.log Lambda
```

**inner.log**

```
[0.011s][info][class,load] opened: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\lib\modules
[0.022s][info][class,load] java.lang.Object source: jrt:/java.base
[0.022s][info][class,load] java.io.Serializable source: jrt:/java.base
...
[0.136s][info][class,load] Inner$1 source: file:/C:/Andrei/
[0.136s][info][class,load] java.lang.Shutdown source: jrt:/java.base
[0.136s][info][class,load] java.lang.Shutdown$Lock source: jrt:/java.base
```

**lambda.log**

```
[0.011s][info][class,load] opened: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\lib\modules
[0.022s][info][class,load] java.lang.Object source: jrt:/java.base
[0.022s][info][class,load] java.io.Serializable source: jrt:/java.base
...
[0.159s][info][class,load] Lambda$$Lambda$1/1282788025 source: Lambda
[0.159s][info][class,load] java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory$1 source: jrt:/java.base
[0.159s][info][class,load] java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl$IntrinsicMethodHandle source: jrt:/java.base
[0.159s][info][class,load] java.lang.invoke.SimpleMethodHandle source: jrt:/java.base
[0.159s][info][class,load] sun.invoke.util.Wrapper$1 source: jrt:/java.base
[0.160s][info][class,load] java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/100555887 source: java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm
[0.160s][info][class,load] java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/1983747920 source: java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm
[0.160s][info][class,load] java.lang.Shutdown source: jrt:/java.base
[0.161s][info][class,load] java.lang.Shutdown$Lock source: jrt:/java.base
```

The full output is [here](https://gist.github.com/apangin/8e97b0d9fc71e68352200897100fce80). As we can see, `Inner` required 136 ms and 537 loaded classes, while `Lambda` took 161 ms and 620 loaded classes.

So, in this simple example avoiding a single lambda helped to save 25 ms of startup time with 83 less classes loaded.

**EDIT**

The overhead I've described consists of two parts:

1. Loading and initializing `java.lang.invoke.*` classes - this is the constant part which needs to be done only once.
2. Linking particular lambda call site - this requires invocation of LambdaMetafactory bootstrap method and generating runtime adapter for calling target method. This needs to be done for every lambda, so this part of overhead is proportional to the number of lambdas in the code.

Comment: Also, assuming here and bringing up, if this could possibly be added to the answer. *single lambda helped to save 25 ms of startup time with 83 less classes loaded.* but this would grow exponentially rather than multiplying by the number of lambda as they increase. Am I correct?

Comment: @nullpointer I've updated the answer. The overhead is proportional to the number of lambdas plus the constant overhead needed to load and initialize additional classes.